# Flex clarification needed: width, min(max)Width, explicitWidth, explicitMin(Max)Width, measuredWidth, measuredMinWidth, percentWidth

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, flex4.5

Is anyone able to shortly explain the meaning of the different Flex size properties in a comprehensible way?

What I have so far:

**Actual size**

`width` and `height`. This is the actual (and final) size of the component. If not set explicitly it will be the size that is calculated by applying all layouting rules and percentage sizes.

**Explicit size**

`explicitWidth` and `explicitHeight`. We need both properties to decide whether the actual size needs to be calculated or can just be copied from these properties.

**Measured size**

`measuredWidth`, `measuredHeight`, `measuredMinWidth` and `measuredMinHeight`. The default sizes of a component. The component is supposed to set these sizes in its `measure()` hook. Default sizes apply only if no explicit size is set (e.g. `width` or `explicitHeight`). The min/max measured size is taken into account only in the case of a percentage sizing. The calculated (actual) size cannot be smaller than the measured min size.

**Percentage size**

`percentWidth` and `percentHeight`. Obvious.

**Min size**

`minWidth`, `minHeight`. Returns the min size of the component - either set explicitly or else the default min size set in `measure()`. Allows to set an explicit min size that overrides the default (measured) min size.

**Explicit min size**

`explicitMinWidth`, `explicitMinHeight`. Same role as the explicit size. If set, these values are to use, else the default (measured) min size.

**Max size**

`maxWidth`, `maxHeight`. Returns the max size of the component - either set explicitly or else the default max size `10000`.

**Explicit max size**

`explicitMaxWidth`, `explicitMaxHeight`. Same role as the explicit size or explicit min size. If set, these values are to use in determination of a upper size border, else the default max size `10000`.

HOPE, there are even more size properties to be discussed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Adobe's article](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=size_position_3.html) is a good reference.  The charts at the bottom describe the differences between dimensions and explicit dimensions, as well as max, min, and default dimensions.

There are basically four ways a developer can size a component:

- **Auto**: Let Flex pick the size by not specifying dimensions
- **Pixels**: Set an exact pixel size, using the height and width properties
- **Percent**: Set the size to be a percentage of the parent container
- **Constraint**: Create a constraint-based layout (usually done by anchoring the sides or center of a child component to some part of the viewable region of its container)

Unless you are creating a custom Flex component, the `height`, `width`, `percentHeight`, and `percentWidth` properties are the only attributes needed to configure a component's dimensions.

Gordon Smith of the Flex SDK Team explains it this way:

> For historical reasons related to ease-of-use consideration, the
>   "width" property does double duty. As a setter, it sets the
>   explicitWidth. As a getter, it returns the actual width.

In other words, it sounds like height and width manage these lower-level properties for you.

Comment: What would set/get "width" now do, if there were no "historical reasons"?

Answer (score 1):

Related link: http://www.developmentarc.com/site/sites/default/files/understanding_the_flex_3_lifecycle_v1.0.pdf